# python is not reading the conditional statement?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, conditional-statements, speech-recognition

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import speech_recognition as sr
import winsound
from time import sleep

vish_image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\priyanka\Pictures\Camera Roll\WIN_20200209_13_14_33_Pro.jpg')
vish_image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(vish_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
priya_image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\priyanka\Desktop\harr cascade\p\s.jpg')
priya_image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(priya_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
def convertToRGB(image):
    return cv2.cvtColor(vish_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return cv2.cvtColor(priya_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

priya = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/priyanka/Desktop/harr cascade/classifier/cascade.xml')
vish = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/priyanka/Desktop/harr cascade/vishneshv_frontal_face.xml')
vish_face = vish.detectMultiScale(vish_image_gray, scaleFactor = 1.05, minNeighbors = 7)
priya_face = priya.detectMultiScale(priya_image_gray, scaleFactor = 1.01, minNeighbors = 1)
no_vish_face = vish_face
no_priya_face = priya_face
r = sr.Recognizer()

print("faces found: "+str(len(no_vish_face)))
print("faces found: "+str(len(no_priya_face)))

if np.all(len(no_priya_face) > 1):
    print("yes")
elif np.all(len(no_vish_face) > 1):
    print("Yes")

sleep(1)    
winsound.PlaySound('how are you.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
sleep(0.5)
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio_data = r.record(source, duration=5)
    print("Recognizing...")
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language ="en-AU")
    print(text)

if 'good' in text:
    winsound.PlaySound('i too feel good.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
elif 'bad' in text:
    winsound.PlaySound('that is okay.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

for(x,y,w,h)in vish_face:
    vish_img = cv2.rectangle(vish_image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
for(x,y,w,h)in priya_face:
    img = cv2.rectangle(priya_image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

img = cv2.resize(vish_image, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


cv2.imshow('test_image',vish_img)
cv2.imshow('hello_image',img)
```

So tried a lot of stuff from the internet, but still no luck. I am a primary student and i am programming on a machine learning. I hope you help me. The conditional statement above that play the sound were not playing and i thought it was the problem with the WAV file, I played it in a new python file, fortunately it worked, so I added the print function to test if they were working. I found out it was the problem with the placement of the conditional statement, but I'm not for sure what was the error.

The console displayed:

```
faces found: 1
faces found: 1
```

Then the recordings

Comment: what is your text?

Comment: Python-3, opencv2 and machine-learning

Comment: can you please check type of variable no_vish_face and no_priya_face.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for condition statement failure is the condition itself.
if you look closely,
the length of **no_vish_face** and **no_priya_face** is exactly equal to 1.

```
if np.all(len(no_priya_face) > 1):   # 1 > 1 --> condition False 
    print("yes")
elif np.all(len(no_vish_face) > 1):  # # 1 > 1 --> condition False 
    print("Yes")
```

you need to change your code too,

```
if np.all(len(no_priya_face) >= 1):   # 1 >= 1 --> condition True 
    print("yes")
elif np.all(len(no_vish_face) >= 1):  # # 1 >= 1 --> condition True 
    print("Yes")
```